# how to force close wifi and data roaming

Tags: android

I want to manually close wifi and data roaming in android. After finishing with processing some data i want to enable it back. How can i do this programatically?

I only find this howto but is not working in my android 4.

[How do I program android to look for a particular network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060414/how-do-i-program-android-to-look-for-a-particular-network)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For wifi (requires `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`):

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

For data (requires `android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354530/how-to-enable-data-connection-on-android-2-3)):

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
dataMtd.invoke(mgr, true/false);
```