# How do I program android to look for a particular network? (Issues Following Simple Tutorial)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wifimanager

I'm attempting to use the following example:

[How do I program android to look for a particular network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060414/how-do-i-program-android-to-look-for-a-particular-network)

But I'm unable to execute it due to issues stemming from the line:

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

After that I'm getting several other errors - but [I think] I've followed the tutorial/example precisely.

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context; 

public class Connect extends Activity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connect);
        String networkSSID = "ANDRE-PC_NETWORK";
        String networkPass = "superman";

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   //ssid must be in quotes


        conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\""; 
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 

        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";

        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                 WifiManager.disconnect();
                 WifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                 WifiManager.reconnect();                

                 break;
            }           
         }

    }}
```

ISSUES IN ECLIPSE PROBLEM LOG:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method reconnect() from the type WifiManager   Connect.java        line 41 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method disconnect() from the type WifiManager  Connect.java        line 39 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method enableNetwork(int, boolean) from the type WifiManager   Connect.java        line 40 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to confuse some variable names:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.add(conf);

List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
         wm.disconnect();
         wm.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wm.reconnect();                
         break;
    }           
}
```

`wifiManager` should be `wm` or vice versa. Also `context` should be `this` or just left out as `getSystemService()` is a method of your class.

I am not sure about the issue with `add()`...

**Edit**:

Well `add()` does not exist for `WifiManager` but `addNetwork()` does, so I guess you need that method instead of `add()`

**Edit2**:

You have no idea what you are doing, right? You don't even understand the difference between a class name and a variable name!

`WifiManager wifiManager` <- First is the Type, also known as class. The second one is the variable name. In your `for` loop you use the type/class instead of the variable, so just write `wifiManager` instead of `WifiManager`.

And you should definitively start by understanding the very basics of programming, OOP and Java. Seriously... Learn the language before you try to write it...

Comment: [Updated my source based on your response]

Comment: Updated my source (and problems log) based on your response - still scratching my head