# How to connect wifi via ADB

Tags: android, android-wifi

Wifi has been enabled on my android device. Usually to connect an available network, I input username and password from UI. Is it possible to do it via ADB or shell script?

Comment: the question is nice and i also want to connect but don't know the answer

Comment: I don't think so, you don't have API. through Java or NDK C native

Comment: if you have root you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708886/connecting-to-wi-fi-using-adb-shell

Comment: you can use `adb shell input` and try out through UI

Answer (score 0):

you can enable/disable wifi from command line with:

```
adb shell svc wifi enable|disable
```

regarding specifying the username & password.. hm... maybe this can help: [How do I program android to look for a particular network? (Issues Following Simple Tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782953/how-do-i-program-android-to-look-for-a-particular-network-issues-following-sim)

Answer (score -2):

yes of course its possible I also tried this and found this-> [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)
 i hope this will help you
:)

Answer (score -3):

Install [ADB over WIFI Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bohlool.net.wifiadb&hl=en), add it to your homescreen, enable it. you will be presented with your IP address

open the terminal and try

```
 adb connect <IP>:<PORT>
```